# Oscillation between two values with frequency control

Tags: lua, trigonometry

I'd like to make a simple oscillation between two numbers (0, 1) and get control over frequency (timing). I'm stuck, but I believe that `math.sin` and `os.clock` function may help.

Comment: Hi. It looks like you want to control power percentage on binary-switched circuit. I think that what you are looking for is PWM - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation . Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks mate, but I'd need help on writing a script, the theory reference won't help me that much.

Comment: Well you now know what to look for. https://www.google.com/search?q=PWM+modulation+lua&sxsrf=ALeKk00JQ9_MVVdm9j8h420-8ikrzfjD3Q%3A1616839039365&ei=fwFfYPzYFfGJrwT0m4XwCQ&oq=PWM+modulation+lua&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABMgUIIRCgATIFCCEQoAE6BwgAEEcQsAM6BggAEBYQHlDKUFiwUmC5U2gCcAJ4AIABfIgBnQOSAQMyLjKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwi8lObkmtDvAhXxxIsKHfRNAZ4Q4dUDCA0&uact=5

P.s.: I dont know Lua O:-)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ChrisHinde/0b0e6eaf2efa42faa4d6757d973caf13

I dont know what you want it for, but here someone uses PWM to change brightness of RGB leds with PWM and Lua...

Comment: and here is docs: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/release/modules/pwm/

Comment: are you referrring to NodeMCU?  what you want to do doesn't make much sense in Lua alone. also what do you mean with oscillate between two numbers? how does the transition look like?

Comment: Sorry @Klemikaze I'm doing game development, the script should be self contained and must respond to lua instructions.

Comment: @Piglet I want to switch between values 0 and 1 and back in a certain amount of time. Example 0 (4 milliseconds) 1 (4 milliseconds) 0 (repeat until condition is met).

Comment: I downvoted because you did not include any code from your attempts to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

> but I believe that math.sin and os.clock function may help.
>
> I want to switch between values 0 and 1 and back in a certain amount
> of time. Example 0 (4 milliseconds) 1 (4 milliseconds) 0 (repeat until
> condition is met)

If you want to alternate between 0 and 1 `math.sin` won't help. `math.sin(x)` calculates the sine of x. A time based signal switching between 1 and 0 immediately is usually called a square wave. Using `math.sin` wouldn't make any sense here as the values would transition between 0 and 1 in a sinosodual shape.

To alternate a value between 0 and 1 you can do various things:

```
local value = 0

-- usually in a loop:

if value == 0 then
  value = 1
else
  value = 0
end

-- or

value = value == 0 and 1 or 0

-- or
value = (value + 1) % 2
```

Either trigger this alternation by time or add delays (usually blocks you program) between each alternation.

A timing of 4ms cannot be achieved in vanilla Lua.

1. you're usually on a non-realtime operating system
2. os.clock provides poor accuracy

There is no application I can think of where it would make sense to have a value alternating at 125Hz. Things like this are usually used in microcontrollers, not on a PC.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I've been able to make it, it was simpler that I thought.
I simply created a function for controlling both the frequency and state.

```
function oscillation()
    if state < 1 then
        state = state + 3 * SIM_PERIOD
    else
        state = 0
    end
end
```

`SIM_PERIOD` is an internal variable of the software I'm using, it is similar to `os.clock`.